# How to share an Audio/Image to whatsapp from an iOS app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I would like to make an app that shares audio/photos to Whatsapp. How can I achieve this function. When i'm pressing share button audio/photo should download from remote server and needs to share to whatsapp contacts.

Im doing the app in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

This would be an example function in Swift 3.0:

```
func sendWhatsApp() {
    let date = Date()
    let msg = "Hi my dear friends\(date)"
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(msg)"

    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                print("please install watsapp")
            }
        }
    }
}
```